# How would that regular expression be?

Tags: c#, regex

I  have an expression that follows some rules:

- The character ' must be first and last character
- There can be zero-or-more spaces inside  `''`
- There can be zero-or-more `%` inside  `''`
- There can be zero-or-more words (letters and numbers) inside `''`

Expression:

```
(?i)^(?<q>['])[%\p{Zs}\p{L}\p{N}|()]*\k<q>$
```

Now I need another expression to replace all ) and ( in a string for "TEST" for example, but only when they are not surrounded by ''. 
        The trick is that when ) or ( are surrounded by '' but these characters belong to a different pair of '', it should not pass.

Example of results:

```
    '(' > pass
    ' ( ' > pass
    ')'   > pass
    ' ) '   > pass
    ' content here ' ' )'  > pass
    ' content here' ) ' another content'  > does not pass
```

Note that the first content has its '', and the second as well. Any ) or ( should not pass if its in between them.

I'm not a pro with regular expressions, so if you don't know how it would be, any documentation or tutorial related would be of great help.

Comment: As far as tutorials go i'd rather recommend books... especially those from o'reilly really cut it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex:

```
^.*[()](?=[^']*'(?>(?:[^']*'[^']*){2})*$)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%5b()%5d(%3f%3d%5b%5e%27%5d*%27(%3f%3e(%3f%3a%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%5b%5e%27%5d*)%7b2%7d)*%24)&i=%27(%27+%3e+pass%0d%0a%27+(+%27+%3e+pass%0d%0a%27)%27+++%3e+pass%0d%0a%27+)+%27+++%3e+pass%0d%0a%27+content+here+%27+%27+)%27++%3e+pass%0d%0a%27+content+here%27+)+%27+another+content%27++%3e+does+not+pass%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m).

Code:

```
var rgxHardNut = new Regex(@"^.*[()](?=[^']*'(?>(?:[^']*'[^']*){2})*$)");
var check1 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("'('");  // true
var check2 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("' ( '");// true
var check3 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("')'");  // true
var check4 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("' ) '");// true
var check5 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("' content here ' ' )'"); // true
var check6 = rgxHardNut.IsMatch("' content here' ) ' another content'"); // false
```

Comment: I think this is all now. Florian, `The character ' must be first and last character ` is a condition for the regex OP already has. Now, this is a different regex that does not have to validate this criterion.

Comment: It took me 1 hour to figure out the regex but like 2 minutes to just code an algorithm ...

Comment: @Th3B0Y: Please let me know if you need more assistance with this problem you had. If not, please consider accepting the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^'[^']*?'(?:(?:[^()]*)'[^']*?')*$");
```

**Edit Demo**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^'[^']*?'(?:(?:[^()]*)'[^']*?')*$");

        string shouldPass1 = "'('";
        string shouldPass2 = "' ( '";
        string shouldPass3 = "')'";
        string shouldPass4 = "'('";
        string shouldPass5 = "' content here ' ' )'";
        string shouldFail = "' content here' ) ' another content'";

        Console.WriteLine("Pass1 : {0}",regex.IsMatch(shouldPass1));
        Console.WriteLine("Pass2 : {0}", regex.IsMatch(shouldPass2));
        Console.WriteLine("Pass3 : {0}", regex.IsMatch(shouldPass3));
        Console.WriteLine("Pass4 : {0}", regex.IsMatch(shouldPass4));
        Console.WriteLine("Pass5 : {0}", regex.IsMatch(shouldPass5));
        Console.WriteLine("Fail : {0}", regex.IsMatch(shouldFail));

        string wholeThing = string.Format(
            "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}",
            shouldPass1,
            shouldPass2,
            shouldPass3,
            shouldPass4,
            shouldPass5,
            shouldFail);

        Console.WriteLine("Alltogether (should fail too): {0}", regex.IsMatch(wholeThing));
    }
}
```

Or without Regex ([Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) would be proud of me):

```
private static bool IsMatch(string text)
{
    bool result = text[0] == '\'' && text[text.Length - 1] == '\'';
    bool opened = false;

    for (int i = 0; result && i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char currentchar = text[i];

        if (currentchar == '\'')
        {
            opened = !opened;
        }
        if (!opened && (currentchar == '(' || currentchar == ')'))
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```