# New rule to existing regex allowing single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I asked [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678100/how-would-that-regular-expression-be), but I still am having problems with it.

I have an expression that follows some rules:

- The character ' must be first and last character
- There can be zero-or-more spaces inside  ''
- There can be zero-or-more % inside  ''
- There can be zero-or-more words (letters and numbers) inside ''
  Expression:

  ```
  (?i)^(?<q>['])[%\p{Zs}\p{L}\p{N}|()]*\k<q>$
  ```

Now, there must be another rule:

- There can be zero-or-more words between '' pairs.

**Example:**

```
'content1' this text should pass 'content2'
```

**Update:**

The trick here is that the following should also pass:

```
' content ' text ' > pass
' ' content ' > pass
```

What would it look like? If you know any good books about regular expressions, it would also be useful to me.

Comment: I suggest reading **Mastering Regular Expressions** by *Jeffrey E.F. Friedl*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that to an alternative list using `|` operator:

```
^(?<q>')(?:'[^']*'|[%\p{Zs}\p{L}\p{N}|()])*\k<q>$
```

I removed the `[]` around `'` and placed the `*` quantifier to the alternative list. Also, `(?i)` is redundant since there are no literal letters in your regex.

Here is the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cq%3E%27)(%3F%3A%27%5B%5E%27%5D*%27%7C%5B%25%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%7C()%5D)*%5Ck%3Cq%3E%24&i=%27content1%27%20this%20text%20should%20pass%20%27content2%27)

Mind that this `'content1' it won't pass 'content2'` won't pass, but I guess it is expected behavior.

**Update**:

If you just want to allow `'` in between `'...'`, you can just add it to the character class:

```
^(?<q>')['%\p{Zs}\p{L}\p{N}|()]*\k<q>$
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cq%3E%27)%5B%27%25%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%7C()%5D*%5Ck%3Cq%3E%5Cr%3F%24&i=%27content1%27%20this%20text%20should%20pass%20%27content2%27%0D%0A%27%20content%20%27%20text%20%27%0D%0A%27%20%27%20content%20%27&o=m) (`\r?` is added for demo purposes in multiline mode there)

Comment: That is a good solution, to the problem. I'll chose your answer. but I forgot to mention that the case:
' content ' text ' should also pass. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Please check my update, I think you want to just allow any number of `'` inside the string.

Comment: The character % must pass (according to the rule: There can be zero-or-more % inside ''). That is 

' % ' tec. sss' > should pass

Comment: If you don't use dot in your string it works. Special characters should be allowed, I'm new to regex, I thought that in "words" it included special characters.

Comment: A dot is not a special character, it is punctuation covered by `\p{P}` shorthand class. Or perhaps, you'd better add the allowed punctuation into the character class. Like this: ^(?<q>')[%\p{Zs}\p{L}\p{N}|():;,.<>~`!@#$^&*{}\\[\\]\\"?/'+-]*\k<q>$.

Comment: That is awesome. Could you recommend me a good book about regex?

Comment: I have not read any, no time :( I read [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info), [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/), and test regexes using [regex101.com](regex101.com), [debuggex.com](http://debuggex.com), [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester), and test performance of .NET regex on [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/). Also, there is a lot on SO to read about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81519/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-th3b0y).